# Maven can't get access to parent properties

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml

I have following structure:

```
parent-pom (pom)
 |
  - base-component (with <parent> parent-pom </parent>)(pom)
    |
    -- child-component (with <parent> base-component </parent>)(jar)
    -- some-folder/another-child (with <parent> base-component </parent>)(jar)
```

In parent-pom I have properties with versions like

```
<properties>
 <product-version>3.7.8</product-version>
</properties>
```

When I build `child-component` and use there `${product-version}` - it is built without errors.
But when I trying to build `another-child`(with child-component as dependency) - maven can't read `${product-version}` or throws an error `Could not find artifact base-component` even if I set `<relativePath>`.

I think the problem is folder between base-component and another-child, but I can't move it to level up.

Any ideas?

Comment: does "another-child" use the correct parent?

Comment: @wemu I think yes, and "another-child" is <module> in the base-component.

Comment: As far as I remember, you can define the order within the <modules>-section.
Either build the children in the correct order, or simply build the parent which has the correct order.
Maybe you need another POM-project as wrapper for that one level where your subfolder resides.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the relative path is set correctly in the `another-child` module. Since it's under another directory, its parent `base-component` should be up by two directories:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>base-component</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
    <relativePath>../../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

Also make sure that in the `base-component` project, the module definition includes the additional path for `another-child`, so it should be something like:

```
<modules>
    <module>child-component</module>
    <module>some-folder/another-child</module>
</modules>
```

Before building `another-child` (or any other sub-module), try to build (`mvn install`) the whole project, starting at the root parent.

Comment: Thanks, I already have described configuration. It works only if I build base-component first. Is there any way to separately build sub-module (another-child) without building base-component first?

Comment: @DmitriyLarkin What do you exactly mean by _"if I build base-component first"?_ If you build `base-component`, `child-component` and `another-child` are built as well. That's the idea of aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting on the pom the project directory.

Parent:

```
<properties>
    <main.basedir>${project.basedir}</main.basedir>
</properties>
```

Sibbling/children:

```
<properties>
    <main.basedir>${project.parent.basedir}</main.basedir>
</properties>
```

children/ grandchildren:

```
<properties>
    <main.basedir>${project.parent.parent.basedir}</main.basedir>
</properties>
```